# assesment for php application code

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks for reading.... still on my way to really getting the hang of php an MySQL queries.

I have a system that queries table entries... I have managed the joining of the 2 tables in my sql query.

Sample:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from table1,table2 where `field_table1` = `field_table2` and `x`= 'x' and y = 'y'")
```

My question on the validation for this query... The joined field in table1 has to be the same as field in table2. Is an if statement the solution and how would I approach this?

Basically I do not want the query to show the result of the search if field_table1 is not = to field_table2.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking, but you should probably read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: If you're still learning PHP, **do not** waste any time learning `mysql_query`. It's a deprecated interface from the 1990s that's in the process of being removed. Learning a modern interface like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) is not hard, it takes about half an hour at most, and gives you the tools to write SQL code that's safe from [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) without making a mess of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
   FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON...
WHERE table1.field != table2.field
```

That should pretty much take care of it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses, it is truly a blessing knowing that there are still people helping others. I will be looking into the PDO as mentioned.

@SamA the sulotion did not work though. I will paste my code as is in the php file hope it will help you to help me lol.

$term = $_POST['term'];

 
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from users,ref_employees where   `user_id` != `employerid` and `idnumber`= '$term'  and employed = '1'  ")
   or die('Error in query : $sql. ' .mysql_error());
   
{